# HTTP 404 error with Response.Redirect

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm getting the following error:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been
>   removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

with the following code:

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=bpnaidu-pc\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=UserLogIn;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");

cn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand( "INSERT INTO regd values('" + ddl_signup.Text + "','" + txt_user.Text + "','" + txtEmail1.Text+ "','" + txtPassword.Text + "','" + txtConPassword.Text + "')", cn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Response.Redirect("welcome to "+txt_user.Text.ToString());
Response.Redirect("Home.aspx"); 
cn.Close();
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Although the question isn't directly clear, the answer is. The problem is on this line:

```
Response.Redirect("welcome to "+txt_user.Text.ToString());
```

Response.Redirect sends a browser to the webpage specified in the parameter, so you're trying to send the browser to a page called "welcome to {...}". I find this unlikely. I suspect what you really want is:

```
Response.Write("welcome to "+txt_user.Text.ToString());
```

Response.Write just sends a text string straight into the HTTP output buffer.

However you follow this up immediately with a redirect to `Home.aspx`, so in reality the line actually does nothing as no sooner have you written the output out that you tell the browser to redirect to a different page, so the user will not see your welcome message.

I'd also like to point out that you're open to a SQL Injection attack as well - your line:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand( "INSERT INTO regd values('" + ddl_signup.Text + "','" + txt_user.Text + "','" + txtEmail1.Text+ "','" + txtPassword.Text + "','" + txtConPassword.Text + "')", cn);
```

...is open to a user doing bad things; if `txt_user.Text` contains the text `'); drop table regd;` there's a good chance you'll end up with a missing regd table. To fix, you need to use parameterised SQL statements. Rather than correct this here, I strongly recommend you follow up by reading Jeff Atwood's [blog article about this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) and how to mitigate.